# ASP.NET web.config SMTP security exception when sending e-mail from web site

Tags: asp.net, web-config, smtpclient

I'm hosting my ASP.NET site at our ISP. Whenever I want to send an e-mail from my site, I get the following error:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type System.Configuration.ConfigurationPermission, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' failed."

I am also getting the following error, which is the original error I had tried to resolve:

> Request for ConfigurationPermission failed while attempting to access configuration section system.net/mailSettings/smtp'. To allow all callers to access the data for this section, set section attribute 'requirePermission' equal 'false' in the configuration file where this section is declared.

I tried to add a config section and set `requirePermission="false"`, but it's not working. Perhaps the type is wrong? Everything works fine locally. Any help to get permission to read my SMTP details from my `web.config` would be great.

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="mailSettings">
    <section name="smtp" type="System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection" requirePermission="false"/>
  </sectionGroup>           
</configSections>
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="...">
      <network  host="..." defaultCredentials="false" userName="..." password="..." />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Does it work on your local machine? Then probably your hosting company has a custom trust-level, which disallows setting the mailSettings. You better contact them to get this fixed.

Comment: Yes works perfect locally. I also suspect that, isn't there a way to bypass this security issue? For instance setting a section and set requirePermission = false? And if so, any advice on if the way I implemented it is correct? Doubt I will be able to ask the hosting company to change trust-levels :( Thanks

Comment: It looks like you implemented it correctly, basically because it works locally. I don;t think you can bypass it, otherwise they wouldn't call it security ;) I also doubt the will change the trust-level, but sometimes they have an alternative way to get it to work. Contacting them seems the best option here. Good luck! Btw, sometimes it's possible to receive the Trust-configuration from the hosting company, so you can test it correctly locally.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I will contact them, perhaps they can provide me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To see a working example of the system.net config section open machine.config on your machine for the version you are targeting.  In ASP .net 4.0 this is how it looks in my machine.config